# couchbaseTemplate.save(List<Employee>) wanted to save multiple Object in one go

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I wanted to save multiple Employee object in couchbase document,but bothered about the use case what will happen when, I have List object of size 5.
suppose when it saved 3 object with 3-documents in couchbase document, some how couchbase server gets down while saving rest 2-document, what will happen in that case.
1) does my all saved document gets rollbacked?
2) does it will also persist another 2 document.?
3) if not both, what will recommended option for this use case.??

Answer (score 0):

From the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#version):

> Couchbase Server does not support multi-document transactions or rollback.

So neither 1. nor 2. will happen.

If you need such transaction guarantees, you have to either use a database product that supports them or implement them on your own.

The typical approach in working with non-transactional stores is, not to rely on consistency. For example by working with idempotent actions, i.e. in the case of a failure you can redo the action.

In the specific example, you might be able to first store the 5 documents, combined as a single document and then split it up in a separate process. The first write is protected by a transaction, and the second process can get repeated until it succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @jens-schauder's answer:
If you have at least 3 nodes in your Couchbase cluster, then the issue should not happen.
Say a node goes down, the cluster will automatically failover what this node was master of (1/3rd of data) to the 2 other nodes, thus writing will work seamlessly.